# Why are `true` and `false` both considered variables?

Tags: c++, definition

I am new to C++ (and quite new to programming overall) and I was reading my C++ college book ("Starting out with C++ Early Objects" 9th edition by Gaddis, Walters and Muganda) when I came across a note on the bool data type.

"NOTE: Notice that true and false do not have quotation marks around them. This is because they are variables, not strings."

Now, from what I've learned, variables can be changed. I understand that a variable of the bool data type would be a variable, but how come `true` and `false` are considered variables?

From my understanding, `false` is stored as an integer value `0` and `true` as an integer value `1`. I tried assigning values `x` where `x` is `0<x<0` to a bool and they all output `1` which made me come to the conclusion that `true` is also everything other than `0` (in other words, true is the same as `!false`?).

So if this is true, how come 'false' is considered a variable and not a constant?

Comment: Both `true` and `false` are keywords, and they are values.  They are not variables.

Comment: Apparently the authors were not careful in their word choice when they wanted to point out the difference between string literals and non-(string literals). Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/11683 for better options.

Comment: In their defence, they do also state at the start of that boolean variable section that _"`true` is a special integer variable whose value is 1"_ and same for `false` being 0, implying that they are constant.

Comment: Oh yeah, I saw that. They didn't bring up constants yet in this book so I guess that must be why. It confused me is all. Thank you for the helpful responses :)

Comment: It's not what is usually called a constant either. It's a keyword denoting a literal.

Comment: List of C++ keywords (including `true` and `false`): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword.  `true` and `false` are Boolean literals, the same way `42` is an integer literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re using a book that shows clear lack of understanding of the subject matter by the author. That book is lying to you. Throw it in the trash.

`true` and `false` are Boolean literals: they are a straightforward way of writing down a value of type `bool`. `"true"` and `"false"` are string literals – and, unfortunately, C++ can help you shoot yourself in the foot by converting them to their address, and then to a Boolean. So you get this wonderful nugget:

```
bool b1 = "false"; // string contents don’t matter
assert(b1 == true);
using book = bool;
book b2 = false;
assert(b2 == false);
```

The asserts are a way of writing true statements in the code: they mean that, at the point they appear, the condition in the parentheses must be true.

`true` and `false` are stored in whatever way the compiler desires – this is an implementation detail and the standard places no requirements here, other than `true` having to convert to `1` in numerical context, and `false` having to convert to `0` there. Usually they are not stored as integers, but bytes (`char`), i.e.

```
assert(sizeof(int) > sizeof(bool));
```

Comment: Did you intend the pun with `book b2`?

Comment: I don't manage to compile that code with a bool being defined as a string, I think you misinterpreted my question. I set the bools to integer values, not strings. Nevertheless, your answer was quite helpful, thank you :)

Comment: You mean that the strings will convert to their adress in RAM, right? And then be converted to booleans. That means they will have a value that is not zero, and will therefore be true. That is what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Henrik That’s correct. C and C++ have this nasty problem of automatically converting an array to the address of its first element. It seemed a good idea at the time…

Comment: @GSerg It was a very solid Freudian slip. Duly noted.